# LocalForage drop instance dosen't seem to do anything

Tags: angular, typescript, localforage

I'm using localForage for a offline map store, these exist for individual areas in a map, with the area id as the key and the localForage instance as the value of the map. When a user wants to delete a particular areas stored data, a method is called that attempts to drop the instance from the map and then remove it from the map, but for some reason this dosen't actually seem to do anything.

Here is the delete method

spTiles is the map of instances which are created and added to the map on downloading area data

```
public async deleteTilesForArea(areaId: number): Promise<boolean> {
    const tileSet = spTiles.get(areaId);
    const keyIter = spTiles.keys()
    console.log("key loop")
    for (let k of keyIter) {
      console.log("Key: " + k)
    }
    console.log("Tile Set? : " + !!tileSet)
    if(!!tileSet) {
      try {
        // Ensure any asynchronous operations are complete before deletion
        await tileSet.ready();
    
        console.log("Pre Delete Length: total: " + spTiles.size);

        await tileSet.length().then(res => "Pre Delete Tile Length: " + res)
        
        // Assuming dropInstance is an asynchronous operation, you might want to await it
        await tileSet.dropInstance();
    
        // Ensure that the instance is fully closed or cleaned up
        await tileSet.clear();

        await tileSet.length().then(res => "Post Delete Tile Length: " + res)
    
        spTiles.delete(areaId);
        console.log("Post Delete Length: " + spTiles.size);
    
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error deleting localforage instance:', error);
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I tried returning an observable of the boolean and subscribing to it but this dosen't seem to change anything